# PermissionError: [Errno 13] - I'm running into this error on my Ubuntu / WSL setup when trying to use 'brownie' package from Github

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, unix, windows-subsystem-for-linux

PermissionError: [Errno 13]  `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/wardu/nft-mix-main' -> '/home/wardu/nft'` - I'm running into this error on my Ubuntu / WSL1 setup when trying to use 'brownie' package from Github. I'm not entirely sure what the Permission is denied to, is it the /home/wardu/nft-mix-main directory?

I have tried `chown -R wardu:admin /home/wardu/nft-mix-main` which didn't work, I received `chown: changing ownership of '/home/wardu/nft-mix-main/': Operation not permitted`.

Any ideas what I need Permissions to and how to get them?   Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your question.  A few follow-up questions:  (a) WSL1 or WSL2?  I *doubt* it matters, but I do have a slight hunch that it might for this (b) Can you add the output of `stat ~`, `stat ~/nft`, and `stat ~/nft-mix-main` to your question?

Comment: Thank you .....        WS1                                                                     
```wardu@Winny:~$ stat ~
  File: /home/wardu
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 2h/2d   Inode: 4222124650991874  Links: 1
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/   wardu)   Gid: ( 1000/   wardu)
Access: 2021-10-11 09:29:41.500890600 +0100
Modify: 2021-10-08 13:10:02.607541500 +0100
Change: 2021-10-08 13:10:02.607541500 +0100
 Birth: -
wardu@Winny:~$ ```

Comment: ```wardu@Winny:~$ stat ~/nft
stat: cannot stat '/home/wardu/nft': No such file or directory
wardu@Winny:~$ stat ~/nft-mix-main
  File: /home/wardu/nft-mix-main
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 2h/2d   Inode: 1688849860823907  Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/   wardu)   Gid: ( 1000/   wardu)
Access: 2021-10-11 09:29:44.415652100 +0100
Modify: 2021-10-08 13:10:02.625642700 +0100
Change: 2021-10-08 13:10:02.625642700 +0100
 Birth: -```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.